# Options for dealing with Android 6.0's new permissions requirements from a service or model component?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm looking into porting some existing code to take Android M's new way of dealing with permissions into consideration. However the permission API needs to have an activity associated with it (for example the requestPermissions() method's first parameter is an activity).

So how should a service that needs to check if a permissions has been granted and request for permissions use this new API if the service doesn't have an activity?

Is it possible for the service to create a dummy invisible activity just for use with the permissions API? (if its possible I don't like the thought of doing that anyway though).

Or suppose its not a service but a model class that needs to perform a permissions check, in MVC a model shouldn't have any knowledge of the Vs and Cs and yet now either it has to in order to know which Activity to use with the permission API. Or potentially lots of code might have to migrate from model code into Activity code.

Any thoughts on how to migrate non activity based code that needs to check/prompt for permissions over to Android 6.0?

**Update:** I left out an important piece of information - this is code that is pre-installed (our company provides code that device manufacture's place in rom) and often may be run at device boot time and run in the background. Therefore the usual situation of a user being prompted for permission when they launch the app or later (and there therefore being an activity at that point) does not necessarily apply.

Comment: Also check out SupportAnnotations (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations) with the @RequiresPermission lets you specify that calling a method will need a permission.

Comment: Thanks for the answers folks. I'll read and digest them and accept one on Monday when I'm more focused then on a Friday afternoon ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how should a service that needs to check if a permissions has been granted and request for permissions use this new API if the service doesn't have an activity?

There is almost always an activity, except for pre-installed apps and plugins for other apps. Otherwise, your service is unlikely to ever run, as nothing will have used an explicit `Intent` to start up one of your app's components, so it will remain in the stopped state.

For the ~99.9% of Android apps that have an activity already, if the permissions are needed for the whole operation of the app, request them on first run. As Snild Dolkow notes, if the user later revokes the permission through Settings, you can detect that without an activity, then use other UI options (e.g., `Notification`, app widget) to let the user know that operation is suspended until they grant you the permissions again, which they would then do through your activity.

> Is it possible for the service to create a dummy invisible activity just for use with the permissions API?

Presumably you can have a `Theme.NoDisplay` activity use `requestPermissions()`. However, from the user's standpoint, it will not make much sense, unless there's some alternative UI (app widget?) that they are interacting with. Popping up a permission dialog out of nowhere is unlikely to make you popular.

**UPDATE 2019-06-15**: Note that Android Q bans services popping up activities frmo the background. Please use a notification instead.

> in MVC a model shouldn't have any knowledge of the Vs and Cs and yet now either it has to in order to know which Activity to use with the permission API

Do not touch the models until you have requested the permission, and gracefully fail if the permission is revoked. You already have to gracefully fail in other circumstances (out of disk space, no Internet connection, etc.), so a revoked permission should be handled in much the same way.

> using this new 6.0 API seems like an recipe for bad design and tight coupling

You are welcome to your opinion. Based on what I have read, the Android engineers believe that asking the user for permissions is part of the user experience and is best handled at the UI layer as a result.

Again: the *vast* majority of Android apps will not have a problem with this, as they have a user interface. Apps that do not have a user interface *and* need `dangerous` permissions are in for some amount of rework.

> this is code that is pre-installed (our company provides code that device manufacture's place in rom) and often may be run at device boot time

First, please understand that this is so far from normal that you can't even *see* normal from where you are due to the curvature of the Earth. :-) You can't really complain that Google did not optimize this particular scenario.

As I understand it, even system apps should be asking for runtime permissions. The Camera app did, for example, on the 6.0 preview. That being said, there's gotta be some database on the device somewhere that is tracking what has been granted, and presumably there is some way to pre-populate it. However, the user could still revoke it from Settings, presumably. But, the manufacturer could pull some stunts (e.g., messing with the Settings app) to possibly even preclude that scenario. I'd be looking in the same area as "how do I get it so my app cannot be force-stopped?" that device manufacturers can do.

Your alternatives would be to get rid of the `dangerous` permissions or to migrate your app off the SDK and into a standard Linux binary that would be run as part of the boot process and be put into a Linux user group that has access to the stuff that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I missed out some relevant information and have updated the question - specifically the code is pre-installed and is not a "typical" app.

Comment: @MartinH: Yeah, I happened to be in here when you edited the question. I have added a bit more to the answer to address that point.

Comment: Regarding pre-population and stopping the user from revoking permissions: Hopefully, the CDD will include rules about that kind of behavior. Okay, maybe privileged system apps should be specially treated, but not other system-installed apps (like Camera, Email, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Ask for it when the user enables whatever feature your service provides. They'll be in one of your activities at the time. Yes, it means that your activities need knowledge of what permissions your services will require.

The service can always *check* for the permission by itself, though, since checkSelfPermission() is available in all Context instances. So you don't need an activity for that.

I guess an alternative would be to have your service post a notification saying "feature X requires you to approve more permissions". Actually, that may be a good idea regardless, in case the user goes into settings and revokes any permissions after the fact. That notification would then take the user to some activity with an "enable feature X" button/checkbox -- ask for the permission when that is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I missed out some relevant info when initially posting, specifically the code is pre-installed and may run in the background on device boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a notification. Look this library to manage the permissions: [permission library](https://github.com/baldapps/PermissionLibrary)